# Where is the Documentation for all of the Javascript HTML Element Constructors?

Tags: javascript, html, browser

I cannot seem to find it. Thanks!

Example:

```
$("#MySelect").append(new Option("MyOption", "MyOption", true, true));
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [Mozilla Dev Center](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs) is the *de facto* standard documentation site for all things JavaScript.

#### `option` element reference:

- [HTML `<option`> element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/HTML/Element/option)
- [`HTMLOptionElement` interface](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/HTMLOptionElement) (which is implemented by the above)
- [W3C `HTMLOptionElement` interface spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-HTML/html.html#ID-70901257)

---

Since you're using jQuery, however, there's [a better way to construct elements](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery2).

```
$('#MySelect').append('<option></option>',
{
    text: 'MyOption',
    value: 'MyOption',
    selected: true
})
```

<sub>I'm not sure what the last `true` argument should do - at least in Chrome, `new Option('text', 'value', true, true)` seems to return the same thing as `new Option('text', 'value', true)`.</sub>

Answer (score 3):

None of the current postings answers the question regarding getting "... Documentation for ALL of the Javascript HTML Element Constructors".  The example is explicitly using the " ... new Option ..." constructor.

This ["answer"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5424571/where-is-the-documentation-for-all-of-the-javascript-html-element-constructors/5424608#5424608/) provides references that do not define any constructors such as `new Option()`.

The [DOM reference provided](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/HTMLOptionElement), should have defined the `Option()` constructor or at least alluded to it.

The programmed constructor `Option()` is NOT HTML and so is NOT defined by the other two references which describe HTML. The  tag element, `<OPTION>` is an HTML defined token so presumably, by implicit precedent only, `new Option()` is the corresponding equivalent constructor, absorbing `<OPTION>` property attributions analogously to other dynamic constructs, but where is this formally, explicitly and emphatically stated to define `new Option()`? In particular, the kind and order of `new Option()`'s parameters would be defined in such a document.

Though it's not a constructor proper, the `createElement() document` method is well defined ( https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.createElement ). Using `document.createElement("option")` with the `HTMLOptionElement` references in this ["answer"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5424571/where-is-the-documentation-for-all-of-the-javascript-html-element-constructors/5424608#5424608/) completely defines such construction.

An [archaic document](http://devedge-temp.mozilla.org/library/manuals/2000/javascript/1.3/reference)  that initiated a legacy of confused paradigms between the DOM, HTML and javascript does define `new Option()` [here](http://devedge-temp.mozilla.org/library/manuals/2000/javascript/1.3/reference/option.html) but is inadequate in the contemporary context.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't know / can't find that doc, You can try using the HTML if you know that.

```
$("#MySelect").append("<option value='myValue'>MyValue</option>");
```

or

```
$("#MySelect").append("<option value='myValue' selected>MyValue</option>");
```

Comment: I don't think that's what the OP is asking for.

Comment: I think this is a better approach since it offload the construction of dom elements to jquery. This means that a difference in javascript implementation in element constructors are hidden from you and done by the jQuery developers leading to probably more crossbrowser support and/or less effort.

Comment: I know that's not what the OP is asking for, I was alerting him to the alternative option.

Answer (score 1):

The syntax you have looks like it might be jQuery - is it?  If so, then [append](http://api.jquery.com/append/) takes an HTML string.  You don't have to create HTMLElement subclasses for it.

[This reference from Mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element) will be helpful in understanding the HTML DOM elements.

[This site](http://krook.org/jsdom/HTMLElement.html) provides javadoc style documentation on the HTMLElement class and its subclasses.

Answer (score 0):

Not really documentation, but I've just published [a short article](https://www.codingexercises.com/a-complete-list-of-all-htmlelement-interface-subclasses) with a list of HTMLElement subclasses. I might expand on it later on.

I've searched the web and couldn't find a list like this. Like I said, it's no documentation, but someone might find it useful having a list of all the subclasses in a single place.