# Where is the new Image() Object defined?

Tags: javascript, image

playing around with some HTML  element I came across a image object declaration

```
var image = new Image();
```

Could somebody tell me where this constructor is defined? I have searched ECMAScript and some hmtl specifications...

Regards

Comment: See also [Where are constructors such as, `new Image()` and `new Option()`, documented?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6936071/where-are-constructors-such-as-new-image-and-new-option-documented)

Answer (score 2):

While being well supported across browsers,  <del>isn't part of any standard</del> the closest `Image()` comes to being part of a standard is [an appearance in the HTML 5 draft](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/embedded-content-0.html#dom-image). There is some [documentation for `Image` on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Image).

I'd generally recommend using [`createElement`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/document.createElement) instead as it provides a consistant API for creating any kind of element and is part of the DOM standards.

Answer (score 0):

It is part of the HTML DOM (not part of ECMAScript), see this link:

[Image API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLImageElement/Image)

Comment: Do you have a better link?

Comment: That isn't documentation for the `Image` function, it is for an `HTMLImageElement` object (which is what `Image()` returns).

Comment: @Quentin, but since `Image` implements `HTMLImageElement` they have the same API, don't they?

Comment: A better collection of sources was suggested in a comment to the OP - [Where are constructors such as, `new Image()` and `new Option()`, documented?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6936071/where-are-constructors-such-as-new-image-and-new-option-documented). W3schools is an unreliable source of documentation, see [w3fools](http://w3fools.com/)

Comment: @Laurent — That's not very good documentation on the part of MDN. `Image` returns an object that implements `HTMLImageElement`.