# Is there a specification for JavaScript Image object?

Tags: javascript

I'm still learning the ropes of JavaScript, and someone pointed out the `Image` object to me.  Having never heard of it, I'd love to look up the specs about what it's supposed to do.  This made me realize that I have no idea where to find specs for JavaScript!

Can anyone point me to whatever is the accepted specs for JavaScript?  Is it just the ECMA standard at http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-262.htm ?  If so, I searched there for the word "Image" and didn't come up with anything useful.

Comment: This is exactly what you want http://www.w3.org/TR/2003/REC-DOM-Level-2-HTML-20030109/html.html#ID-17701901 I know this is not all inclusive but this is the standard out of the w3c Also see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/HTMLImageElement for the Mozilla standard implementation

Comment: Thanks, that is just what I was asking for. Looking at the DOM spec, I see there are a lot of object definitions.  Does this mean I can create new objects of any of those types in all implementations in JavaScript?  What made me wonder was seeing a line of code such as `var img = new window.Image()`.  I suppose I can also do `var anc = new window.Anchor()` if I wanted?

Comment: I believe not all elements have explicit constructors like Image(). The normal way to create an element for the DOM is document.createElement see http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Core/core.html#i-Document

Comment: I guess my question should've been - is there a specification of elements that do have explicit constructors?  I was surprised when I saw that line of code, and wanted to be sure it will work in all browsers.

Comment: I've never seen a complete list of all of them but this looks like a good starting point. I think mostly they are legacy constructors. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6936071/where-are-constructors-such-as-new-image-and-new-option-documented

Comment: Looking through that, that's exactly what I wanted to ask!  Thanks for your great replies.

Comment: Here are two links from MDN about the Image object I found pretty useful. [https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLImageElement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLImageElement) [https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLImageElement.Image](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLImageElement.Image)

Comment: In case you're still confused (or for others) The Image object is part of the Document Object Model (DOM) spec, not Javascript.  It is not part of the Javascript language.