# Object-Natured Functions

Tags: javascript, function, object, constructor

**Context**

I've noticed that some functions can only be called with the `new` prefix. When called without it, the error *Illegal Invocation* is thrown. Below is two examples of how the console reacted when the `Image` was called in different ways.

```
-> new Image();
<- <img>
-> Image();
<- TypeError: DOM object constructor cannot be called as a function.
```

Even more interesting, under closer observation, these types of functions seem like functions, yet they aren't. Take `Image` for example, the `typeof` command reveals that `Image` is a function yet the constructor of `Image` implies that it is an Object.

This is very different than most construction functions like the one below.

```
function Foo(){
    this.identity = 'Bar';
}
```

The function `Foo` can be called two ways, `new Foo()` and `Foo()`. This is very different than the `Image` function.

**The Question**

This action with the `Image` function is very different than most construction functions. How is this possible? Is this why the `new` prefix must be used with `Image`? And more importantly can this type of function be recreated?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the 'new' keyword in JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1646698/what-is-the-new-keyword-in-javascript)

Comment: It isn't I have scoured that question and it doesn't address mine. I am asking why some construction functions require the new prefix while others are indifferent. What makes the difference and how can i recreate it?

Comment: Simple, check if `this` is a `MyObj` with `function MyObj() { if(!(this instanceof MyObj)) throw new TypeError("MyObj must be called as a constructor") }`

Comment: @apsillers: You can do it generically (in case the function name changes) with: `if (!(this instanceof arguments.callee)) throw new Error("Constructor called as a function");` See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/383402/is-javascript-s-new-keyword-considered-harmful).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think this is the logic you're looking for that reproduces the exception when the `new` keyword isn't used to create an instance of `Foo`:

```
function Foo() {
    if (!(this instanceof arguments.callee)) 
        throw new TypeError("DOM object constructor cannot be called as a function.");

    this.identity = 'Bar';
}
```

According to some comments in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/383402/is-javascript-s-new-keyword-considered-harmful), instead of `arguments.callee` you'd have to use the function name `Foo` if you are in strict mode:

```
function Foo() {
    if (!(this instanceof Foo)) 
        throw new TypeError("DOM object constructor cannot be called as a function.");

    this.identity = 'Bar';
}
```

See a **[DEMO here](http://jsfiddle.net/4ZBMt/)** that illustrates the situation.

Comment: "you'd have to use the function name if you're not in strict mode" - You mean "if you *are* in strict mode"

Answer (score 2):

The problem with `Image` is that it is a [host object](http://es5.github.io/#x4.3.8) - which means it does not need to follow the strict semantics of native EcmaScript objects. For example, it can inherit from something that is not `Function.prototype`, implement the internal [[Construct]] method but not [[Call]] and similar things.

They are specified by the DOM (see [Where are constructors such as, `new Image()` and `new Option()`, documented?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6936071/1048572)), specifically [here](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/embedded-content-0.html#dom-image):

> A constructor is provided for creating `HTMLImageElement` objects (in addition to the factory methods from DOM such as `createElement()`): `Image(width, height)`. **When invoked as a constructor**, this must return a new `HTMLImageElement` object (a new img element). […]

Yet it implemented browser-specific: For example Opera creates images without `new` as well, not throwing the `NOT SUPPORTED` error.