# How to add Drop-Down list (<select>) programmatically?

Tags: javascript, html, drop-down-menu, html-select

I want to create a function in order to programmatically add some elements on a page.

Lets say I want to add a drop-down list with four options:

```
<select name="drop1" id="Select1">
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
```

How can I do that?

Comment: Look into `document.createElement` and `element.appendChild`

Comment: @koukouloforos is my answer is helpful?

Comment: @WooCaSh it does what i am asking but i prefer if something in simple javascript.

Comment: @koukouloforos reason? If that's a commercial project, it's highly recommended to use a library.

Comment: @JanDvorak No i am just doing some testing.

Comment: @koukouloforos in which case carry on. It's good to learn how to do it the "hard" way.

Answer (score 256, accepted):

This will work (pure JS, appending to a div of id `myDiv`):

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/4pwvg/

```js
var myParent = document.body;

//Create array of options to be added
var array = ["Volvo","Saab","Mercades","Audi"];

//Create and append select list
var selectList = document.createElement("select");
selectList.id = "mySelect";
myParent.appendChild(selectList);

//Create and append the options
for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    var option = document.createElement("option");
    option.value = array[i];
    option.text = array[i];
    selectList.appendChild(option);
}
```

Comment: It's a miracle! A non-jQuery solution. You might just want to set properties, instead of attributes with `setAttribute()`. And not that it matters, but using `new Option(text, value)` is a nice shortcut for creating `<option>` elements

Comment: @Ian -- Thanks for the tips, still learning pure JS, learned jQuery first unfortunately, trying to be able to do everything in pure JS as well is a bit tricky :)

Comment: @tymeJV Of course, just trying to help improve your answer (although great as it is). Very true though, although sometimes it feels more rewarding when you can do it without jQuery :) For anyone's reference - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6936071/where-are-constructors-such-as-new-image-and-new-option-documented . And I haven't found a need for using `setAttribute()`/`getAttribute()` unless you're working with custom attributes (including `data-*`) attributes. I know there are inconsistencies when using those methods as well, so I stay away

Comment: You can also add options by using `selectList.add(option)` ([spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#dom-select-add) (scroll up a bit), [mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLSelectElement#add()))

Comment: A long time ago add()/remove() worked differently in different browsers, so ppk advised not to use them.  I don't know what the current state of affairs is.

Comment: how would we be able to have a default brand lets say Saab selected?

Answer (score 15):

```
var sel = document.createElement('select');
sel.name = 'drop1';
sel.id = 'Select1';

var cars = [
  "volvo",
  "saab",
  "mercedes",
  "audi"
];

var options_str = "";

cars.forEach( function(car) {
  options_str += '<option value="' + car + '">' + car + '</option>';
});

sel.innerHTML = options_str;


window.onload = function() {
  document.body.appendChild(sel);
};
```

Comment: This is the fastest solution and it works with large data sets.

Comment: @RomanNewaza, Check the speed with the forEach loop replaced by a regular old for-loop.

Comment: Just as a warning, if the select is generated with user created content, this is not a secure way to implement a select

Answer (score 5):

I have quickly made a function that can achieve this, it may not be the best way to do this but it simply works and should be cross browser, please also know that i am NOT a expert in JavaScript so any tips are great :)

## Pure Javascript Create Element Solution

```
function createElement(){
    var element  = document.createElement(arguments[0]),
        text     = arguments[1],
        attr     = arguments[2],
        append   = arguments[3],
        appendTo = arguments[4];

    for(var key = 0; key < Object.keys(attr).length ; key++){
        var name = Object.keys(attr)[key],
             value = attr[name],
             tempAttr = document.createAttribute(name);
             tempAttr.value = value;
        element.setAttributeNode(tempAttr)
    }
    
    if(append){
        for(var _key = 0; _key < append.length; _key++) {
            element.appendChild(append[_key]);
        }
    }

    if(text) element.appendChild(document.createTextNode(text));

    if(appendTo){
        var target = appendTo === 'body' ? document.body : document.getElementById(appendTo);
        target.appendChild(element)
    }       

    return element;
}
```

lets see how we make this

```
<select name="drop1" id="Select1">
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
```

here's how it works

```
    var options = [
        createElement('option', 'Volvo', {value: 'volvo'}),
        createElement('option', 'Saab', {value: 'saab'}),
        createElement('option', 'Mercedes', {value: 'mercedes'}),
        createElement('option', 'Audi', {value: 'audi'})
    ];


    createElement('select', null, // 'select' = name of element to create, null = no text to insert
        {id: 'Select1', name: 'drop1'}, // Attributes to attach
        [options[0], options[1], options[2], options[3]], // append all 4 elements
        'body' // append final element to body - this also takes a element by id without the #
    );
```

this is the params

```
createElement('tagName', 'Text to Insert', {any: 'attribute', here: 'like', id: 'mainContainer'}, [elements, to, append, to, this, element], 'body || container = where to append this element');
```

This function would suit if you have to append many element, if there is any way to improve this answer please let me know.

edit:

Here is a working demo

## [JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ConnorM/ZzHMt/1/)

This can be highly customized to suit your project!

Answer (score 3):

This code would create a select list dynamically. First I create an array with the car names. Second, I create a select element dynamically and assign it to a variable "sEle" and append it to the body of the html document. Then I use a for loop to loop through the array. Third, I dynamically create the option element and assign it to a variable "oEle". Using an if statement, I assign the attributes 'disabled' and 'selected' to the first option element [0] so that it would be selected always and is disabled. I then create a text node array "oTxt" to append the array names and then append the text node to the option element which is later appended to the select element.

```js
var array = ['Select Car', 'Volvo', 'Saab', 'Mervedes', 'Audi'];

var sEle = document.createElement('select');
document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].appendChild(sEle);

for (var i = 0; i < array.length; ++i) {
  var oEle = document.createElement('option');

  if (i == 0) {
    oEle.setAttribute('disabled', 'disabled');
    oEle.setAttribute('selected', 'selected');
  } // end of if loop

  var oTxt = document.createTextNode(array[i]);
  oEle.appendChild(oTxt);

  document.getElementsByTagName('select')[0].appendChild(oEle);
} // end of for loop
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's an ES6 version of the answer provided by [7stud](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17002312/5903923).

```js
const sel = document.createElement('select');
sel.name = 'drop1';
sel.id = 'Select1';

const cars = [
  "Volvo",
  "Saab",
  "Mercedes",
  "Audi",
];

const options = cars.map(car => {
  const value = car.toLowerCase();
  return `<option value="${value}">${car}</option>`;
});

sel.innerHTML = options;

window.onload = () => document.body.appendChild(sel);
```

Comment: This is really strange, you are setting innerHTML to an array. Are you sure this doesn't need `sel.innerHTML = options.join('')`

Comment: Yeah I'm sure. Here's an [example of the code in action](https://codepen.io/Kosai106/pen/GRJbbqP)

Answer (score 1):

```
const countryResolver = (data = [{}]) => {
    const countrySelecter = document.createElement('select');
    countrySelecter.className = `custom-select`;
    countrySelecter.id = `countrySelect`;
    countrySelecter.setAttribute("aria-label", "Example select with button addon");

    let opt = document.createElement("option");
    opt.text = "Select language";
    opt.disabled = true;
    countrySelecter.add(opt, null);
    let i = 0;
    for (let item of data) {
        let opt = document.createElement("option");
        opt.value = item.Id;
        opt.text = `${i++}. ${item.Id} - ${item.Value}(${item.Comment})`;
        countrySelecter.add(opt, null);
    }
    return countrySelecter;
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's an ES6 version, conversion to vanilla JS shouldn't be too hard but I already have jQuery anyways:

```js
function select(options, selected) {
  return Object.entries(options).reduce((r, [k, v]) => r.append($('<option>').val(k).text(v)), $('<select>')).val(selected);
}
$('body').append(select({'option1': 'label 1', 'option2': 'label 2'}, 'option2'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Using `reduce` is a bit overkill here innit? A `map` works just as well for the usecase which OP is describing.

Answer (score 0):

```js
const cars = ['Volvo', 'Saab', 'Mervedes', 'Audi'];

let domSelect = document.createElement('select');
domSelect.multiple = true;
document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].appendChild(domSelect);


for (const i in cars) {
  let optionSelect = document.createElement('option');

  let optText = document.createTextNode(cars[i]);
  optionSelect.appendChild(optText);

  document.getElementsByTagName('select')[0].appendChild(optionSelect);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

it's very simple yet tricky but here is what you wanted, hope it's helpful :
*this function generates a select list from 1990 to 2018 
i think this example can help ya, if you want to add any other value just 
change value of x and y ;)*

```
function dropDown(){
    var start = 1990;
    var today = 2019;
    document.write("<select>");
    for (var i = start ; i <= today; i++)
    document.write("<option>" + i + "</option>");
}
document.write("</select>");

dropDown();
```