# Laravel 5.6, How to Set option value on var.SetAttibute on dynamic form?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, laravel, laravel-5

Excuse me, I'm just learning web developing recently,

I have some trouble on dynamic form, [here's the picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PynCq.png)

I wanna make dynamic form with select type on it.

TAMBAH button = add more field
Simpan button = save,

The problem is, when I want to add more fields, select input did not show as the first one, it become normal input not select.

I know, maybe the problem is from javascript which I don't understand.

here is the code

On Form

```
<td>{{ Form::text('jumlah[]', null, array('class'=>'form-control')) }}</td>
<td>{{ Form::text('satuan[]', null, array('class'=>'form-control')) }}</td>
<td>{{ Form::text('keterangan[]', null, array('class'=>'form-control')) }}</td>
{{ Form::select('status_pi[]', ['Iya' => 'iya', 'Tidak' => 'Tidak'],
'Tidak',array('class'=>'form-control')) }}
```

On Javascript

```
var jumlah = document.createElement('input');
jumlah.setAttribute('name', 'jumlah[' + i + ']');
jumlah.setAttribute('class', 'form-control');

var satuan = document.createElement('input');
satuan.setAttribute('name', 'satuan[' + i + ']');
satuan.setAttribute('class', 'form-control');

var keterangan = document.createElement('input');
keterangan.setAttribute('name', 'keterangan[' + i + ']');
keterangan.setAttribute('class', 'form-control');

var status_pi = document.createElement('input');
status_pi.setAttribute('name', 'status_pi[' + i + ']');
status_pi.setAttribute('selected', 'selected');
status_pi.setAttribute('class', 'form-control');
```

I wanna make var status_pi field appear like on the first one below PI column,

Pls help sensei

Comment: Your call to createElement should use `select` instead of `input`

Comment: It's work sir, the form become select field but it has no option value, what should i do 
 to make the field has value like the first one? i don't know much javascript syntax, and not sure how to google what i mean

Comment: [Try this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17001961/how-to-add-drop-down-list-select-programmatically)

Comment: you didn't use option. you just use select. trying use select & option

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var status_pi = document.createElement('input');
```

Should be:

```
var status_pi = document.createElement('select');
```

As you [can see here](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_select_form) the `input` field is for textfields, and a `select` field is for dropdown menus.

Keep in mind that you probably have to set your `select`'s `<option>` values too in JavaScript.

Comment: How can i set select option on JavaScript sir? can u give me some example regarding my problem?

Comment: Take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8674667/9372943)