# Parsing complete HTML block with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

What is my plan: Every field should contain an input and a select dropdown. I thought it would be smart to insert this element with JavaScript/jQuery (so they can be edited in one place).

Found this solution and it works but not the way I wanted. It passes my HTML block as a string and didn't interpret it as an HTML statement.

Any possible solutions? I found something with `$("#myDiv").html(result);` - could this help me?

```js
function selectBuilder(){
    var node = document.getElementById('select');
    var newNode = document.createElement('div');
    newNode.appendChild(document.createTextNode('<div class=\"select\"><select><option>--Select--</option><option>Hello 1</option><option>Hello 2</option><option>Hello 3</option><option>Hello 4</option></select><div class=\"select_arrow\"></div></div>'));
    node.appendChild(newNode);
}
```

```css
body {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 100%;
    font-family: LatoLatin,Arial,sans-serif;
}

h1{
    text-align: center;
}

.tableContainer{
    width: 95%;
    display: inline-flex;
    justify-content: center;
}
.menuNumber{
    width: 50px;
}

.menuTable {
    border-collapse:collapse;
    border-spacing:0;
    width: 100%;
    border: 1px solid grey;
}

.menuTable td{
    width: 100px;
    text-align: center;
    font-size:14px;
    border: 1px solid grey;
    border-width:1px;
    overflow:hidden;
    word-break:normal;
}

.menuTable th{
    width: auto;
    border: 1px solid grey;
    border-width:1px;
    overflow:hidden;
    word-break:normal;
}

.menuContent{
    height: 150px;
}

.salatContent{
    height: 100px;
}

.menuDesc{
    display: table;
    height: 110px;
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
}

.select {
    display: grid;
    width: 100%;
    height: 40px; 

}

.menuDescItem{
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
    width: inherit;
    height: 110px;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css.css">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.0.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js.js"></script>

</head>
<body onload="selectBuilder()">
<h1>Speiseplan</h1>
    <div class="tableContainer" >
    <table class="menuTable">
      <tr>
        <th class="menuNumber"></th>
        <th class="">Montag</th>
        <th class="">Dienstag</th>
        <th class="">Mittwoch</th>
        <th class="">Donnerstag</th>
        <th class="">Freitag</th>
      </tr>
      <tr class = "menuContent">
        <td class="">1</td>
        <td class="tg-031e">
            <div class = "menuDesc">
                <input type="textarea" class="menuDescItem" name="menuOneDescMonday" autofocus placeholder="Menu 1 Montag" >
            </div>
            <div id="select"><!-- html block should be placed here e.g. --></div> 
        </td>
        <td><div class=""></div></td>
        <td class=""></td>
        <td class=""></td>
        <td class=""></td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="menuContent" >
        <td class="">2</td>
        <td class=""></td>
        <td class=""></td>
        <td class=""></td>
        <td class=""></td>
        <td class=""></td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="menuContent">
        <td class="">3</td>
        <td class=""></td>
        <td class=""></td>
        <td class=""></td>
        <td class=""></td>
        <td class=""></td>
      </tr>
      <tr class= "salatContent">
        <td class="">Salat</td>
        <td class="tg-031e" colspan="5"></td>
      </tr>
    </table>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the sortest way is using `newNode.innerHTML`

```
function selectBuilder() {
  var node = document.getElementById('select');
  var newNode = document.createElement('div');
  newNode.innerHTML = '<div class="select"><select><option>--Select--</option><option>Hello 1</option><option>Hello 2</option><option>Hello 3</option><option>Hello 4</option></select><div class="select_arrow"></div></div>';
  node.appendChild(newNode);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var node = document.getElementById('select'); // get your target element
var selectList = document.createElement("select"); //create new select
var option = document.createElement("option"); //create new option
option.value = "value"; //add value to option
option.text = "text"; //add text to option
selectList.appendChild(option); //add option to select
node.appendChild(selectList); //add selectList to you target
```

You can use for loop to add more options to your select list. Please take a look at this: [How to add Drop-Down list (<select>) programmatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17001961/how-to-add-drop-down-list-select-programmatically)

Comment: It's unclear where OP is getting their HTML string from - we would generally assume that it's an example string so converting to code would not be suitable.  If it's *not* a sample string, then yes this is an alternative method.  Keep answer questions, at 50 rep you can ask comments to clarify, eg "is your HTML fixed or is it an example".

Answer (score 0):

The equivalent jquery (as tagged [jquery]) is to replace your selectBuilder content with

```
function selectBuilder() {
    $("#select").html("<div>" + your_html_string + "</div>")
}
```

it's not clear if you need the extra `<div>` or not.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative approach would be to use the Jquery [templates](https://dzone.com/articles/jquery-templates-%E2%80%93-tmpl).

or you can remote load the template if you dont want to bulky your html page.

```
    <script id="myTemplate" type="text/html">
        <li> ${Attendee} </li>
    </script>
$("#myTemplate").tmpl(myData).appendTo("ul");
```