# Create iframe only using javascript

Tags: javascript, iframe

I am working on a slideshow implementation.  We have to prefetch images for better user experience.  Currently I am using hidden img tags to trigger the image load.  But when a user moves say from 1st image to 80th image, the prefetch image request started for the first image doesn't get cancelled.

Using iframes we can call `stop()` on iframe object to stop loading the previous set of images.  The norm for creating iframes using javascript appears to be

```
ifrm = document.createElement("IFRAME");
```

I dont want to do that as I dont want my iframes to be appended to DOM.  There is a `HTMLFrameElement`.  But I am not sure how to use it.

So my question is, how to create iframes in javascript without accessing document object.

Comment: Why are you adverse to using the `document` object?

Comment: "I want to create an iframe without the one tool that will let me create an iframe". Seems legit.

Comment: @Teemu if it's homework, it's one cruel or (more likely) ignorant teacher.

Comment: You mean you don't want to append the newly created `iframe` to the `document` rather than create the whole element without using `document` object? Partially yes, but depends on, what exactly means "`use that as an iframe`". @joews Unfortenately some teachers are.

Comment: Yes.  I dont want to append it to document.  I think I should explain my usecase properly. Let me edit the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can create an `iframe` to the `document` without appending it, but the accessibility is limited to the `iframe` element itself.

- Unappended elements have not `parentElement` nor `parentNode`
- If you'd lose the reference to `iframe` (`ifrm` in your example), the
  element is gone forever
- You can't access the window within the `iframe` or the loaded document
- `onload` event of the `iframe` is not fired

You can change for example `src` or size of an unappended `iframe`. And yes, the content is loaded asynchronously related to the main page.

Comment: Edited the question.  So how to create the iframe element?

Comment: @AnirudhanJ Exactly how you've done it in your example. Just store the iframes into an array instead of a bunch of variables. Though you can't create any HTMLElement without accessing `document`, since all elements are just properties in document object. HTMLFrameElement (`<frame>`) is deprecated, it has been used with framesets. However, I think you've an XY-problem here, using iframes is hardly a solution to your problem. Maybe you better post a question about the original problem, with an example code.

Answer (score 3):

The code you posted is the solution.

You cannot write equivalent code without using `document` (and why would you want to?). You need to use [Javascript's interface](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document_Object_Model/Introduction#How_Do_I_Access_the_DOM.3F) to the [DOM](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document_Object_Model), which is provided through `document` (or `window`).

You can use [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) and other DOM-aware libraries to abstract away the DOM API calls, but under the covers they all call `document` methods.

Comment: Is there any way to create a HTMLFrameElement object and use that as an iframe? Just like how we use new Image() for creating images in javascript.

Comment: I'm not very familiar with that style of creating elements. Maybe this question could help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6936071/where-are-constructors-such-as-new-image-and-new-option-documented